# MYSQL loop in function not working

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a mysql function which will change records accordingly . But loop only execute for one time and leaves loop with this condition. "IF v_finished =1 THEN
        LEAVE get_stock;
    END IF;"

However its is supposed to execute multiple time. Like in my test case 3 times

```
BEGIN

DECLARE P_stock int(11);
DECLARE P_product int(11);
DECLARE V_From_warehouse int(11);
DECLARE V_To_warehouse int(11);
DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE V_To_warehouse_stock int(11);
DECLARE V_From_warehouse_stock int(11);



declare cur1 cursor for 
        SELECT material_transfer_details.product_id , material_transfer_details.quantity  FROM
            material_transfers,
            material_transfer_details
        WHERE
            material_transfers.id = material_transfer_details.mtm_id
        AND
            material_transfers.status = 'Y'
        AND 
            material_transfers.id = V_MTM_id;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

SELECT warehouse_from INTO V_From_warehouse FROM material_transfers WHERE id =V_MTM_id; 

SELECT warehouse_to INTO V_To_warehouse FROM material_transfers WHERE id =V_MTM_id;


OPEN cur1;

get_stock: LOOP

 IF v_finished =1 THEN
        LEAVE get_stock;
    END IF;

fetch cur1 into P_product , P_stock;

SELECT quantity INTO V_To_warehouse_stock from stocks where warehouse_id = V_To_warehouse and product_id = P_product;

SELECT quantity INTO V_From_warehouse_stock from stocks where warehouse_id = V_From_warehouse and product_id = P_product;



IF (V_To_warehouse_stock IS NOT NULL)
THEN
    UPDATE 
        stocks SET quantity = quantity - P_stock 
    WHERE
        warehouse_id = V_to_warehouse 
        AND
            product_id = P_product;
ELSE

    INSERT INTO stocks(product_id , warehouse_id , quantity ,status, created_datetime , updated_datetime) values 
        (P_product , V_to_warehouse , 0-P_stock , 'Y', sysdate() , sysdate()); 


END IF;



IF (V_From_warehouse_stock IS NOT NULL)
THEN
    UPDATE 
        stocks SET quantity = quantity + P_stock 
    WHERE
        warehouse_id = V_from_warehouse 
        AND
            product_id = P_product;
ELSE

    INSERT INTO stocks(product_id , warehouse_id , quantity ,status, created_datetime , updated_datetime) values 
        (P_product , V_from_warehouse , P_stock , 'Y', sysdate() , sysdate()); 


END IF;

SET P_stock = 0;
SET P_product = 0;

END LOOP get_stock;

CLOSE cur1;




UPDATE material_transfers SET Status = 'N' WHERE id= V_MTM_id;

UPDATE material_transfer_details SET Status = 'N' WHERE mtm_id = V_MTM_id;

return '00000';

END
```

Comment: how many rows that cur1 holds, i mean that select scrict is returning any rows or not. First check that once.

Comment: It is returning 3 rows. I have checked it manually

Comment: The `continue handler for not found` will not only act on a cursor, but also if e.g. `SELECT warehouse_to INTO V_To_warehouse ...` doesn't find any rows - which you obviously expect, since you test for that in `IF (V_To_warehouse_stock IS NOT NULL)`. You can add another handler; you can set a variable before you fetch a new row (so you can check that variable in the handler); or other similar ways.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, change your code.

```
get_stock: LOOP

  SET v_finished = FALSE;

  fetch cur1 into P_product , P_stock;

  IF v_finished =1 THEN
    LEAVE get_stock;
  END IF;
```

Since you are doing other things that could trip the handler, reset `v_finished`, then fetch from the cursor, and *only then* test whether to leave the loop.

As written, if you hadn't tripped the handler prematurely, you would have been testing in entirely the wrong place and would have stayed in the loop too long.

Next... be sure you understand `SELECT ... INTO`.  I don't think it does quite what you think it does.

A scalar subquery is a much safer solution:

```
SET V_To_warehouse_stock = (SELECT quantity from stocks where warehouse_id = V_To_warehouse and product_id = P_product);
```

If `SELECT ... INTO` returns no rows, the variable's value does not change.  It retains its former value, if one exists, and that is rarely what you expect.

Spooky action at a distance like this is best avoided, and it's an easy trap to fall into, in a loop.

See examples of this effect at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35207/11651.